# Chain observables but listen to second observable changes

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm piping two observables

```
this.obs1$
  .pipe(
    skip(1),
    mergeMap(schedules => {
      this.schedules=schedules
      for (let elm in schedules) {
        ....
      }
      return this.selectedDate$;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(selectedDate => {
   ....
```

the problem is that subscribe does not send data if `Obs1$` is not triggered.

What I would like to get `selectedDate$` values even when `Obs1$`does not change, but `selectedDate$` should run always after `Obs1$`

Comment: So you want to listen to both observables independently of each other, but also use the first observable to trigger a call to the second observable?

Comment: what you are trying to do is not clear. Can you explicit some exemples of how you want it to work ?

Comment: `Obs1$`is emmiting only one value, but the second obs is emitting many values. I use the only one value that `Obs1$`emits subscription every time `selectedDate$`emits value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest`.

```
combineLatest([
    this.obs1$,
    this.selectedDate$
]).subscribe(([obs1Value, selectedDate]) => {...})
```

Now every time `obs1$` or `selectedDate$` is changed, it will trigger the subscription.

But keep in mind this will only work if both observables emit at least one value. If you wanna ensure the subscription is triggered even when you're not sure `this.obs1$` will be triggered at all, you can chain it with `startWith` pipe which will ensure one value will be emitted.

```
this.obs1$.pipe(startWith('defaultValue'))
```

Comment: I have commented my question to clarify better my problem

Comment: Ok, then you don't need the startWith, just using the combineLatest should do the job.